# Convert ISO 8601 strings to date in createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

I have a block of JSON returned from a REST API in the following format:

```
[
  { 
    id: 1,
    locations: [
      {
        arriveAt: "2015-03-14T16:05:16Z"
      },
      {
        arriveAt: null
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I then have code in my project like this:

```
let trips = json as [NSDictionary]
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
for trip in trips {
  Trip.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(trip)
}
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

In my Location class, there is a var `dynamic var arriveAt: NSDate?`. I also extended NSDate with a `fromISO8601String` method which initializes NSDate converting the ISO 8601 string to a date.

Is there a way that when Realm tries to create the Location object, it would automatically run the string from the JSON through `NSDate.fromISO8601String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Dave there isn't anything built into Realm yet that can do that for you. You will need to use a transformer like [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON), or Mantle, etc.

Comment: I ended up manually parsing each block of the JSON and then pulling it all together at the end.

Comment: That works too :), good to hear! We are working on a navtive solution to make this easier

Comment: it would be great if you could apply filters when processing data from an API into Realm.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would want to see?

Comment: I added it as an issue on the Realm-Cocoa GitHub repo. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1641

Comment: Great thanks, the team will use that to help build the feature!

Comment: Thanks! So far I'm loving Realm. Replaced CoreData with it in 2 days on this app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73101/discussion-between-yoshyosh-and-dave-long).